# Are atexit() registered handlers called just one time?

Tags: c

I have a program with a function registered with `atexit()`:

```
atexit(exitFunc);
```

And a signal handler like this:

```
void sigHandler(int sigNo)
{
  switch (sigNo)
  {
  case SIGINT:
  case SIGTERM:
  case SIGHUP:
    exit(0);
    break;
  }
}
```

I have checked that first time I send SIGINT to the process, `exitFunc()` is called when `exit(0)` is executed. However, if the process is still running (`exitFunc()` make take a while) and I send SIGNIT again, `exitFunc()` is not called again when `exit(0)` terminates the process instantanly.

<strike>Is this normal behaviour?</strike> A function registered with `atexit()` is only called one time? Should I re-registered `exitFunc()` again if I want it to be called next time I reach `exit(0)`?

(I have had a look to [atexit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atexit.htm) documentation, but that specific point is not clear)

Comment: Function `exit` is not async-signal-safe, so you should not call it from a signal handler. See the table in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html I suggest to modify a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` in your signal handler, check this variable in your main processing and call `exit` when indicated by the variable value.

Comment: To answer the question "Is this normal behaviour? A function registered with atexit() is only called one time?" Yes.

Comment: The `exit` manual page seems to suggest that `POSIX.1` declares that calling `exit` multiple times is undefined behaviour.

Comment: After seening the comments, I have edited my question to remove "Is this normal behaviour?" as this can be confussing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear from [`man 3 atexit`](https://manned.org/atexit.3) that functions registered with `atexit` are only called *once*:

> The same function may be registered multiple times: it is called once for each registration.

If you want the function to be called multiple times, you should re-register it multiple times when/if needed. However, be careful, since what you are trying to accomplish has very dubious utility. If whatever you are doing requires to re-register the same function with `atexit` after `exit()` is called, you might want to think about other approaches.

In your example, since `sigHandler()` is a signal handler, you are restricted and can only call async signal safe functions, see [`man 7 signal safety`](https://manned.org/signal-safety.7) for a list. Note that `exit()` is *not* amongst those, so calling `exit()` from `sigHandler()` is undefined behavior. Whatever the specification says, you're breaking it. The only way you can safely exit from a signal handler it by using [`_exit()`](https://manned.org/_exit.2) (note the leading underscore), which does a direct exit without any cleanup.

If you need to do cleanup, but you still want to exit from a signal handler, then do the cleanup in the signal handler itself and call `_exit()` when done. If you need non async signal safe functions to do cleanup, use the signal handler to simply set a global variable and then check it when needed in your main program: if set, do the cleanup and exit (now you *can* use `exit()`).